Transmitting SPI data Wirelessly
i have a sensor that communicates via SPI and is wired. I want to use a wireless communication protocol, like an NRF24, to mirror the SPI data wirelessly instead of using the cables. This way, the software I use will still think the sensor is connected as if it were wired, but it will work with the spoofed data. How is this possible?
basically i want the spi data mirrored into another mcu,
when it's; rp2040; <-> sensor
i want to use it like; rp2040 <-> wireless protocol <-> rp2040 <-> sensor
The reason i want to transmit SPI data directly is that application is running on a whole firmware and it doesnt support wireless communications so i need to fake it to use wireless

What clock rate is the SPI running at? It is probably not going to be possible. The wireless link would have to run at a speed much greater than the clock rate.

it doesnt support wireless communications ... please do not say what it does not support ... say what it supports

most of the STM32s and RP2040. also a linux host as serial

Isn't max spi speed is 50mhz? how will it make problems if i transmit data over 2.4GHz?

No SPI has mHz max frequency. MHz, yes.

It is possible in many ways. You cannot extend SPI wirelessly, or you can but it would be quite inefficient.
What you need might be two MCUs with a wireless link between them, and then tell the other MCU to do what you want.
You can either forget that there is a SPI sensor over a wireless link alltogether and just have the sensor side MCU to provide you the info you need wirelessly while it handles the SPI sensor. As an example, main MCU sends a command to remote MCU to return sensor data, e.g. temperature. The remote MCU may send cached data or go fetch temperature via SPI and send it back. The main point is, the main MCU does not need to know which sensor there is over which kind of bus at the remote MCU, so it does not need to know there is a SPI sensor. The remote MCU of course needs to abstract this and know how to fetch data from sensor over the SPI bus.
Or maybe a dummy approach of telling the sensor-side MCU to send/receive SPI bytes in a transaction without any understanding what it is communicating with, as long as it gets the data it must send and returns you data it needs.
Then your main MCU can simply say to the remote MCU to do any kind of SPI transactions to achieve what you want to do with the sensor. Like a remote procedure call to do SPI transactions like locally.

Thanks, though do you think putting infrared leds on the CS, MISO, MOSI and SCLK and put a receiever on the other side to couple them wirelessly will work?

@arteuspw It makes no sense. All receivers would see all IR LEDs at the same time. Unless you use optical fiber. Even with IR link, you would maybe send infrared data packets between two MCUs, not to a SPI chip. Simply put, you need two MCUs or equivalent of two MCUs to access a SPI chip wirelessly.

Aren't SPI signals 0 and 1? just blink when it's high and don't blink when it's low(?) is this what a 'infrared data packet' is?

Yes SPI signals are either 0 or 1. But please think for a moment how are you going to arrange four transmitters and four receivers so that only one receiver sees only one transmitter. Are you going to put them 1cm apart and wrap them with black tape keeping each transmitter pointing at one receiver? Or communicate freely on a table, in  a single room, with multiple devices in a single room with someone using a TV remote, or device in a different room?

I get your point, besides that i wanted to ask if i can transmit SPI signals if that wasnt a problem, also what about Nrf24s?

@arteuspw Are NRF24 chips capable of being SPI hosts? If not, you can communicate anything between two MCUs. It's up to you what you communicate between two MCUs and whether that is raw SPI data transactions or whatever sensor data you need from the SPI sensor anyway regardless of it being SPI bus, I2C bus, UART or any other bus. It's just messages, like you can send "hello" message to your friend or ask "what's the temperature there" via SMS, Whatsapp, email, letter, postcard or phone call and your friend will respond the temperature, whether it was a digital or analog thermometer.
